# Tensorflow tf.hessian returns only zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hessian

I have a trained keras model of which I need to compute both the gradients and hessian of the output respect to the input.
The input `X` is a 5000x3 numpy array and the output `y` is 5000x1.

The gradient computation works fine both using keras' gradients and tensorflow's gradients functions, and I get an array 5000x3 with the correct values in it, but the hessian using tf.hessian() returns only zeros.
This should not be the case as my model is approximating a highly nonlinear function, so that second derivatives are well expected to be nonzero.

The code is the following (I simplified some parameters for redeability):

```
def get_derivatives_NN(X, y):

    # Define Keras model
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(500, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1]))

    # Compile and fit model
    optimz = keras.optimizers.Adam(optimizer_parameters)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimz, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    model.fit(X, y, epochs = 200, validation_split=0)

    # Evaluate gradients in Keras
    grads = keras.backend.gradients(model.output, model.input)[0] # tensor
    get_gradients = keras.backend.function([model.input], [grads])
    evaluated_gradients = get_gradients([X]) # this is the evaluated gradient in Keras

    # Evaluate gradienst in tf
    session = keras.backend.get_session()
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    evaluated_gradients_TF = session.run(tf.gradients(model.output, model.input), feed_dict={model.input: X})

    # Evaluate hessian in tf
    evaluated_hessian = session.run(tf.hessians(model.output, model.input), feed_dict={model.input: X})

    return evaluated_gradients, evaluated_gradients_TF, evaluated_hessian
```

The output is (truncating my copy-paste):

```
GRADIENT KERAS:
[array([[-0.00286908,  0.06114262,  0.0178928 ],
       [-0.00717778,  0.05055936,  0.0415092 ],
       [-0.00725342,  0.0075229 ,  0.06268862],
       ..., dtype=float32)]


GRADIENT TF:
[array([[-0.00286908,  0.06114262,  0.0178928 ],
       [-0.00717778,  0.05055936,  0.0415092 ],
       [-0.00725342,  0.0075229 ,  0.06268862],
       ..., dtype=float32)]

HESSIAN TF:
[array([[[[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]], ....... etcetera
```

There are two problems with this:

1) The size of the hessian doesn't really make sense to me. I expected a (5000, 3, 3) array, or a (5000,9) at most, while I get a (5000, 3, 5000, 3);

2) The values are all zeros, I have checked with `np.count_nonzero(evaluated_hessian)` which returns `0`.

I would understand if both the gradient and the hessian calculation failed, then it would be clear I have made something silly... but gradients works fine while hessians fails, and the docs seem to indicate they both obey to the same syntax call, which is what I have done here.
Any help as to why this is happening?

EDIT:
If I use the calculated gradient as input for another `get_derivative_NN` call I get the correct value for the second derivative out, so this proves that there is something strange going on with the `tf.hessians()` function.

Comment: For the size of the Hessian, it is normal. Indeed, if $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is your scalar function, the hessian will be $\left(  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i} \partial x_j  \right)_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$, of size $n \times n$.

Comment: @MrMaths Besides your notation not making sense, note that your "hessian" is a square matrix, while the one returned here has 4 dimensions, with 2 different values. I therefore cannot see how you can claim it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "using the calculated gradient as an input for another `get_derivative` call"? Are you referring to `get_derivatives_NN`?

Comment: I apologise for the late reply, somehow I never received a notification about you posting.
Yes, I meant `get_derivative_NN`, thanks for catching the typo. I have updated the text in my original question.